# Display own data only for users in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I currently have made a page that shows all the users, but I just want to only display the currently logged in user, Please help me im begging you I spent 4 hours of nothing T_T im new at php and im very lost, im so hopeless right now

```
<?PHP
$customerquery=mysql_query("select * from customerinfo");
while($customerrows=mysql_fetch_array($customerquery)){
?>
<tr>
<td>Id</td><td>First Name</td><td>Last Name</td><td>Address</td><td>Contact No</td>   <td>Username</td><td>Password</td><td>Edit</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><?PHP echo $customerrows['id'];?></td>
<td><?PHP echo $customerrows['fname'];?></td>
<td><?PHP echo $customerrows['lname'];?></td>
<td><?PHP echo $customerrows['address'];?></td>
<td><?PHP echo $customerrows['contactno'];?></td>
<td><?PHP echo $customerrows['username'];?></td>
<td><?PHP echo $customerrows['password'];?></td>
<td><a href="edit2.php<?PHP echo '?id='.$customerrows['id']; ?>">edit</a></td>
</tr>
<?PHP } ?>
```

Comment: Take a look at PDO or mysqli, since the mysql extension you are using is considered deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify a WHERE condition in your query. That will fetch only one row, so you will not need a while loop:

```
$id = (int) $_GET['id']; // assuming you pass user id in URL
$customerquery = mysql_query("select * from customerinfo WHERE id = $id");
$customerrows = mysql_fetch_array($customerquery);
// rest of your html
```

Comment: tnx for your helpful answer T_T ill try this out

Comment: I've done passing the user id in the url but my problem now is im having an error called unidentified id do u know how to solve it sir?

Comment: It seems the name of identifier column in your customerinfo table is not "id". (may be its Id). You need to replace `id =` with the valid  column name in WHERE condition: `WHERE valididcolumn = $id`

Comment: ok sir ill give it a shot goodluck to me, anyways tnx for the help sir :)